# Issue when running android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

when i try to run two or more emulators at the same time this error appears(Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_6P_API_23 was killed.
) and only one works fine but the others are dead

the error image

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMQjj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You create new emulators using the Android SDK manager's ("SDK Manager.exe", located in your android install directory) "Virtual Devices" tab.

You can then start them in the command prompt using:

```
emulator -avd <avd_name>
```

More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Comment: first , thanks for reply , i know this way but it seems that there is a problem in my android studio that i can't launch two or more emulators simultaneously

Comment: You can have two AVDs running in Android Studio just not two of the same devices. When you start a device, it locks it's necessary files. This lock causes and error when you try to start a second instance of the same device. To solve this just create another device via AVD manager and then you should not have a problem running them both at the same time.

Comment: i already created another device i am testing on (Nexus 6p , Nexus 9)

Comment: Look at the picture I added to the answer, I did it on my Android Studio and it works.

Comment: i changed the system API and it worked it had an issue in accessing the same image , thanks